# Como pasar múltiple datos array, objetc de un componente a otro - Angular

Tags: angular

Amigos quisiera que me puedan ayudar,
todo lo que está en esa imagen esta en 1 componente y dentro utiliza otros componentes.
Pero quisiera sacar el cuerpo en otro componente para tan solo agregar `<app-cuerpo></app-cuerpo>`
me llame a toda su funcionalidad, pero cuando lo ingreso ya no se grafica

a comienzos estaba así:
**Kaypacha.component.html**

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFill class="base">
    <div *ngIf="!layout.isMobile && !loading" fxLayout="column" fxFill>
        <div fxLayout="row" style="height: 115px;">
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center start" fxLayout="column">
                <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/kaypacha_logo.png" style="height: 88px;">
                <div fxFlex style="padding-left: 15px;font-weight: bold;"><span>ASESOR: {{cabeceraConfig.nombre}}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/copa.jpg" style="height: 115px;">
                </div>
                <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/personas.png" style="height: 115px;">
                </div>
                <div fxLayoutAlign="center center"  > 
                 
                    <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/ranking.png"   mat-button color="primary" class="bus-bot" (click)="showVarCard(0)" style="height: 115px;">
               
                </div>
                <div>
                    <mat-card class="pos-card" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                        <span>Posición</span>
                        <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold;">{{cabeceraConfig.posicion}}</span>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button *ngIf="cabeceraConfig.boton" mat-button color="primary" class="bus-bot" (click)="openSearch()">
                        <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 36px;">
                            switch_account
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/fc.png" style="height: 115px; width: 190px;">
            </div>
        
        </div>    
      
          <div fxFlex fxLayout="column" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <div fxLaout="row" >
                <div>
                    <app-preguntas-kaypacha [config]="preguntasConfig"></app-preguntas-kaypacha>
                </div>
                <div fxFlex fxLayout="column">
                    <div>
                        <app-puntaje-kaypacha [config]="puntajeConfig"></app-puntaje-kaypacha>
                    </div>
                    <div fxFlex style="padding-top: 12px;">
                        <app-desempenio-kaypacha [config]="desempenioConfig"></app-desempenio-kaypacha>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex>
                <div style="max-height: 278px;height: 100%;">
                    <div fxFlex >
                        <app-dinamizadores-kaypacha [config]="dinamizadoresConfig"></app-dinamizadores-kaypacha>
                    </div>
                    <div fxFlex="40">
                        <app-bonos-kaypacha [config]="bonosConfig"></app-bonos-kaypacha>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
      
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!layout.isMobile && loading" fxLayout="column" fxFill fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <img src="assets/images/fc/mis_wait.png" alt="" style="width: 120px;height: 120px;">
        <div><span>Cargando...</span></div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="layout.isMobile" fxLayout="column" fxFill fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <img src="assets/images/fc/kaypacha1.png" alt="" style="width: 240px;height: 300px;">
        <span style="text-align: center;">Por el momento el módulo solo se puede visualizar correctamente en una PC/laptop.</span>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

**Kaypacha.component.ts**

```
export class KaypachaComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
loading: boolean = true;
cabeceraConfig:any;
preguntasConfig:any;
bonosConfig:any;
puntajeConfig:any;
desempenioConfig:any;
dinamizadoresConfig:any;

constructor(public layout: LayoutService, private ant: ModKaypachaService, 
        public dialog: MatDialog, public user: UserService) {

    }

ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        
    }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.cabeceraConfig=cloneDeep(cabeceraConfig); 
this.preguntasConfig=cloneDeep(preguntasConfig);
this.bonosConfig=cloneDeep(bonosConfig);
this.puntajeConfig=cloneDeep(puntajeConfig);
this.desempenioConfig=cloneDeep(desempenioConfig);
this.dinamizadoresConfig={i1:baseDinamizadoresConfig.line,i2:baseDinamizadoresConfig.line};
this.getServerData();

}

private getServerData(codBT?: string): void {
        this.loading = true;
        let profile = this.user.get('profile');
        this.ant.getDashboardData(codBT).subscribe(x => {
            let r = x.body.resultado;
            this.cabeceraConfig.nombre = r.bloq.col_nom;
            this.cabeceraConfig.posicion = onNullOrUndefined(r.bloq.rank, "--");
            if (!codBT && (r.pars.hab_bot == "1" || profile.tip_use == 0)) {
                this.cabeceraConfig.boton = true;
            }
            let d:string = r.pars.din_lis;
             
            if(!isNullOrUndefined(d)){
                let a:any = JSON.parse(d);
                a.forEach((x:any,i:number)=>{
                    let b:any;
                    if(x.type=="column"){
                        b = cloneDeep(baseDinamizadoresConfig.column);
                    }else {
                        b = cloneDeep(baseDinamizadoresConfig.line);
                    }
                    b.title=x.title;
                    b.options.colors[0]=x.color;
                    this.dinamizadoresConfig['i'+i]=b;
                });
            }
            console.log(r.his)
            this.setBloqConfig(this.preguntasConfig, r.bloq.bloq_par);
            this.setBloqConfig(this.bonosConfig, r.bloq.bloq_acum); 
            this.setHistConfig(this.desempenioConfig, r.his, "bloq_des");
            this.setHistConfig(this.dinamizadoresConfig, r.his, "bloq_din");
            this.puntajeConfig.anio = r.bloq.anio;
            r.his.forEach((v, i) => {
                this.puntajeConfig.hist[i] = v.punt;
            });
            this.puntajeConfig.hist[12] = onNullOrUndefined(r.bloq.punt_tot, '--');
            this.loading = false;
        });
    }

    private setHistConfig(base: any, cfg: any, key: string) {
        cfg.forEach((v: any, i: number) => {
            if (v[key]) {
                let co: any = JSON.parse(v[key]);
                Object.keys(base).forEach(k => {
                    if (co[k]) {
                        base[k]['hist'][i] = co[k];
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

     private setBloqConfig(base: any, cfg: any): void { 
         if (cfg) {
             let j = JSON.parse(cfg);
             Object.keys(j).forEach(k => {
                 base[k]['val'] = j[k];
             });
         }
     }

openSearch(): void {
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.data = {
            showCloseBtn: true
        }; 
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BuscadorKaypachaComponent, dialogConfig);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(v => {
            if (v) { this.getServerData(v.cod_bt);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**lo que modifique**

**Kaypacha.component.html**

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFill class="base">
    <div *ngIf="!layout.isMobile && !loading" fxLayout="column" fxFill>
        <div fxLayout="row" style="height: 115px;">
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center start" fxLayout="column">
                <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/kaypacha_logo.png" style="height: 88px;">
                <div fxFlex style="padding-left: 15px;font-weight: bold;"><span>ASESOR: {{cabeceraConfig.nombre}}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/copa.jpg" style="height: 115px;">
                </div>
                <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/personas.png" style="height: 115px;">
                </div>
                <div fxLayoutAlign="center center"  > 
                 
                    <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/ranking.png"   mat-button color="primary" class="bus-bot" (click)="showVarCard(0)" style="height: 115px;">
               
                </div>
                <div>
                    <mat-card class="pos-card" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                        <span>Posición</span>
                        <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold;">{{cabeceraConfig.posicion}}</span>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button *ngIf="cabeceraConfig.boton" mat-button color="primary" class="bus-bot" (click)="openSearch()">
                        <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 36px;">
                            switch_account
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <img src="assets/images/fc/modules/kaypacha/fc.png" style="height: 115px; width: 190px;">
            </div>
        
        </div>
         <div fxFlex fxLayout="column" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <app-panel></app-panel>
        </div>     
       
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!layout.isMobile && loading" fxLayout="column" fxFill fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <img src="assets/images/fc/mis_wait.png" alt="" style="width: 120px;height: 120px;">
        <div><span>Cargando...</span></div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="layout.isMobile" fxLayout="column" fxFill fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <img src="assets/images/fc/kaypacha1.png" alt="" style="width: 240px;height: 300px;">
        <span style="text-align: center;">Por el momento el módulo solo se puede visualizar correctamente en una PC/laptop.</span>
        <!--<span style="text-align: center;">Pronto estará disponible la vista móvil. Gracias por su comprensión.</span>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**kaypacha.component.ts**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
// import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
import { AfterContentInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { isNullOrUndefined, onNullOrUndefined } from "app/core/shared/functions.util";
import { LayoutService } from "app/system/admin/services/layout.service";
import { ModKaypachaService } from "./compartido/servicio/mod-kaypacha.service";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { BuscadorKaypachaComponent } from './buscador/buscador.component';
import { UserService } from 'app/system/admin/services/user.service';
//import { bonosConfig, cabeceraConfig, desempenioConfig, baseDinamizadoresConfig, preguntasConfig, puntajeConfig } from './kaypacha.util';
import { PanelComponent } from './panel/panel.component';
//import { bonosConfig, cabeceraConfig, desempenioConfig, baseDinamizadoresConfig, preguntasConfig, puntajeConfig } from './panel/panel.util';
//import {  cabeceraConfig} from './panel/panel.util';
import {  cabeceraConfig,bonosConfig, desempenioConfig, baseDinamizadoresConfig, preguntasConfig, puntajeConfig  } from './kaypacha.util';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-kaypacha',
    templateUrl: './kaypacha.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./kaypacha.component.scss'],
    //providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class KaypachaComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
    //Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
    loading: boolean = true;

    cabeceraConfig:any;
    
    @ViewChild(PanelComponent) panelComponent: PanelComponent;

    constructor(public layout: LayoutService,  public dialog: MatDialog,
        public router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
       
        const cabeceraConfig = {
            nombre: '--',
            posicion: '--',
            boton: false
        }; 
           this.cabeceraConfig=cabeceraConfig
           this.cabeceraConfig.boton = true;
           this.loading = false;
         
        
    } 

    openSearch(): void {
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.data = {
            showCloseBtn: true
        }; 
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BuscadorKaypachaComponent, dialogConfig);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(v => {
            if (v) {
                this.panelComponent.getServerData(v.cod_bt)
                this.cabeceraConfig= this.panelComponent.cabeceraConfig 
           
            }
        });
    }
     

}
```

**Cree un nuevo componente llamado Panel para colocar todo el cuerpo**

**panel.component.ts**

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="column" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <div fxLaout="row" >
   <div>
            <app-preguntas-kaypacha [config]="preguntasConfig"></app-preguntas-kaypacha>
        </div>  
        <div fxFlex fxLayout="column">
              <div>
                <app-puntaje-kaypacha [config]="puntajeConfig"></app-puntaje-kaypacha>
            </div>  
            <div fxFlex style="padding-top: 12px;">
                <app-desempenio-kaypacha [config]="desempenioConfig"></app-desempenio-kaypacha>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex>
        <div style="max-height: 278px;height: 100%;">
            <div fxFlex >
                <app-dinamizadores-kaypacha [config]="dinamizadoresConfig"></app-dinamizadores-kaypacha>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="40">
                <app-bonos-kaypacha [config]="bonosConfig"></app-bonos-kaypacha>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**panel.component.ts**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
import { AfterContentInit, Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { isNullOrUndefined, onNullOrUndefined } from "app/core/shared/functions.util";
import { LayoutService } from "app/system/admin/services/layout.service";
import { ModKaypachaService } from "../compartido/servicio/mod-kaypacha.service";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { BuscadorKaypachaComponent } from '../buscador/buscador.component';
import { UserService } from 'app/system/admin/services/user.service';
import { bonosConfig, cabeceraConfig, desempenioConfig, baseDinamizadoresConfig, preguntasConfig, puntajeConfig } from './panel.util';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
//import { bonosConfig, cabeceraConfig, desempenioConfig, baseDinamizadoresConfig, preguntasConfig, puntajeConfig } from '../kaypacha.util'; 
@Component({
    selector: 'app-panel',
    templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./panel.component.scss'],
    //providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
    Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
    loading: boolean = true;

    cabeceraConfig:any;
    preguntasConfig:any;
    bonosConfig:any;
    puntajeConfig:any;
    desempenioConfig:any;
    dinamizadoresConfig:any;

    constructor(public layout: LayoutService, private ant: ModKaypachaService, 
        public dialog: MatDialog, public user: UserService,
        public router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        
    }

    ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.cabeceraConfig=cloneDeep(cabeceraConfig);
        this.preguntasConfig=cloneDeep(preguntasConfig);
        this.bonosConfig=cloneDeep(bonosConfig);
        this.puntajeConfig=cloneDeep(puntajeConfig);
        this.desempenioConfig=cloneDeep(desempenioConfig);
        console.log(this.desempenioConfig)
        this.dinamizadoresConfig={i1:baseDinamizadoresConfig.line,i2:baseDinamizadoresConfig.line};
        this.getServerData();

           
    }

      public getServerData(codBT?: string): void {
        this.loading = true;
        let profile = this.user.get('profile');
        this.ant.getDashboardData(codBT).subscribe(x => { 
            let r = x.body.resultado;
            this.cabeceraConfig.nombre = r.bloq.col_nom;
            this.cabeceraConfig.posicion = onNullOrUndefined(r.bloq.rank, "--");
            if (!codBT && (r.pars.hab_bot == "1" || profile.tip_use == 0)) {
                this.cabeceraConfig.boton = true;
            }
            let d:string = r.pars.din_lis;  
            if(!isNullOrUndefined(d)){ 
                let a:any = JSON.parse(d);
                a.forEach((x:any,i:number)=>{
                    let b:any; 
                    if(x.type=="column"){
                        b = cloneDeep(baseDinamizadoresConfig.column); 
                    }else {
                        b = cloneDeep(baseDinamizadoresConfig.line);
                    }
                    b.title=x.title;
                    b.options.colors[0]=x.color;
                    this.dinamizadoresConfig['i'+i]=b; 
                });
            }   
            this.setBloqConfig(this.preguntasConfig, r.bloq.bloq_par);
            this.setBloqConfig(this.bonosConfig, r.bloq.bloq_acum);  
            this.setHistConfig(this.desempenioConfig, r.his, "bloq_des"); 
            this.setHistConfig(this.dinamizadoresConfig, r.his, "bloq_din");
           console.log(this.desempenioConfig)
            this.puntajeConfig.anio = r.bloq.anio; 
            r.his.forEach((v, i) => {
                this.puntajeConfig.hist[i] = v.punt;
            });
            this.puntajeConfig.hist[12] = onNullOrUndefined(r.bloq.punt_tot, '--'); 
            this.loading = false;
        });
    }

    public setHistConfig(base: any, cfg: any, key: string) { 
        cfg.forEach((v: any, i: number) => {
            if (v[key]) {
                let co: any = JSON.parse(v[key]);  
                Object.keys(base).forEach(k => {
                    if (co[k]) {  
                        base[k]['hist'][i] = co[k];
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public setBloqConfig(base: any, cfg: any): void { 
        if (cfg) {
            let j = JSON.parse(cfg); 
            Object.keys(j).forEach(k => { 
                base[k]['val'] = j[k]; 
            });
        }
    }
 
    showVarCard(i: number) {
        if (this.layout.isMobile) {
          //this.incentivos2.setCardData(i);
          //this.router.navigateByUrl('variable', { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,skipLocationChange: true });
          this.router.navigate(['./ranking'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,skipLocationChange: true});   
        }
      }
    

}
```

**Kaypacha.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { SharedCWCModule } from "app/core/screen/components/shared-cwc.module";
import { SharedMaterialModule } from "app/core/screen/components/shared-material.module";
//import { SharedPrimengModule } from "app/core/screen/components/shared-primeng.module";
import { SharedCMCModule } from "../shared/components/shared-cmc.module";
import { KaypachaRoutingModule } from "./kaypacha-routing.module";
import { KaypachaComponent } from "./kaypacha.component";
import { PreguntasKaypachaComponent } from "./preguntas/preguntas.component";
import { PuntajeKaypachaComponent } from "./puntaje/puntaje.component";
import { DesempenioKaypachaComponent } from './desempenio/desempenio.component';
import { DinamizadoresKaypachaComponent } from './dinamizadores/dinamizadores.component';
import { BonosKaypachaComponent } from './bonos/bonos.component';
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { ModKaypachaService } from "./compartido/servicio/mod-kaypacha.service";
import { BuscadorKaypachaComponent } from './buscador/buscador.component';
import { PanelComponent } from "./panel/panel.component";
import { RankingComponent } from "./ranking/ranking.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        KaypachaRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        SharedMaterialModule, 
        SharedCWCModule,
        SharedCMCModule,
        HighchartsChartModule
    ],
       declarations: [PanelComponent,KaypachaComponent, PreguntasKaypachaComponent, PuntajeKaypachaComponent,
            DesempenioKaypachaComponent, DinamizadoresKaypachaComponent, BonosKaypachaComponent, 
            BuscadorKaypachaComponent,RankingComponent], 
    providers: [ModKaypachaService]
})
export class KaypachaModule { }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Kaypacha-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { KaypachaComponent } from "./kaypacha.component";
import { PanelComponent } from "./panel/panel.component";
import { RankingComponent } from "./ranking/ranking.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        component:KaypachaComponent,
        //component:PanelComponent,
        data: {title:'Kaypacha'},
        children: [ 
            {
                path:'ranking',
                component: RankingComponent
            } 
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class KaypachaRoutingModule { }
```

**Panel.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { SharedCWCModule } from "app/core/screen/components/shared-cwc.module";
import { SharedMaterialModule } from "app/core/screen/components/shared-material.module";
//import { SharedPrimengModule } from "app/core/screen/components/shared-primeng.module";
//import { SharedCMCModule } from "../shared/components/shared-cmc.module";
//import { KaypachaRoutingModule } from "./kaypacha-routing.module";
//import { KaypachaComponent } from "./kaypacha.component";
import { PreguntasKaypachaComponent } from "../preguntas/preguntas.component";
import { PuntajeKaypachaComponent } from "../puntaje/puntaje.component";
//import { DesempenioKaypachaComponent } from '../desempenio/desempenio.component';
import { DinamizadoresKaypachaComponent } from '../dinamizadores/dinamizadores.component';
import { BonosKaypachaComponent } from '../bonos/bonos.component';
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { ModKaypachaService } from "../compartido/servicio/mod-kaypacha.service";
import { BuscadorKaypachaComponent } from '../buscador/buscador.component';
import { PanelRoutingModule } from "./panel-routing.module";
import { PanelComponent } from "./panel.component";
import { SharedCMCModule } from "app/modules/shared/components/shared-cmc.module";
import { KaypachaComponent } from "../kaypacha.component";
import { DesempenioKaypachaComponent } from "../desempenio/desempenio.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        PanelRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        SharedMaterialModule, 
        SharedCWCModule,
        SharedCMCModule,
        HighchartsChartModule
    ],
      declarations: [ 
          PanelComponent, PreguntasKaypachaComponent, 
          PuntajeKaypachaComponent,
         DesempenioKaypachaComponent, DinamizadoresKaypachaComponent, 
        BonosKaypachaComponent, BuscadorKaypachaComponent,KaypachaComponent],
     
    providers: [ModKaypachaService]
})
export class PanelModule { }
```

**panel-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { PanelComponent } from "./panel.component"; 

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        component:PanelComponent,
        data: {title:'Kaypacha'}
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PanelRoutingModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
  const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'session/signin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: AuthLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'session',
            loadChildren: () => import('./system/session/session.module').then(m => m.SessionModule),
            data: { title: 'Session' }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        canActivate: [LoginGuard],
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'app',
        redirectTo: 'app/desktop',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'app',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'desktop',
            component: DesktopComponent,
            data: { title: 'Desktop' }
          },
          {
            path: 'reportes',
            loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/reportes/rep01.module').then(m => m.Rep01Module),
            data: { title: 'Reportes' }
          } 
          {
            path: 'kaypacha', 
            loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/kaypacha/kaypacha.module').then(m => m.KaypachaModule),
            data: { title: 'Kaypacha' }
          }
        ]
      },
    ];
    
    @NgModule({ 
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Hola, necesitas ser un poco más explicito. Donde pusiste tu componente nuevo `cuerpo`? Lo agregaste al app.modules? Ó al modulo donde lo quieres llamar?

Comment: podrías mostrar el enrutamiento  y también la arquitectura modular los módulos que usas

Comment: @Legna ahora lo detallo  mil gracias

Comment: @nestdan mil gracias ahora lo coloco

Comment: @nestdan lo acabo de modificar

Comment: no veo las rutas....la consola que error te da

Comment: en las rutas me refiero a app-routing.module.ts

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139956/discussion-between-pierodev-and-nestdan).

Comment: @nestdan lo agregue amigo , podemos verlo en el chat ?

Comment: @nestdan listo amigo, pero creo que el problema es donde he creado el component PANEL que no le llega la información

Comment: Si mejor importas tu proyecto en stackblitz y nos compartes?...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev lo que pasa es que para obtener data llama para el servicio

Comment: por fa si me pueden ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno investigando encontre un decorador @Input que manda datos del padre al hijo
así que en método que generaba el padre y obtenia los datos tuve que crear varios decoradores @Input y pasarle la data, quedaria así, cabe resaltar que no se si está bien o se **puede mejorar**:

**Kaypacha.component.ts (Padre)**

```
recibidodesempeno: any;
recibidopregunta: any;
recibidopuntajeConfig: any;
recibidobonosConfig: any;
recibidodinamizadoresConfig: any; 

Public getServerData(codBT?: string): void {
this.recibidodesempeno=this.desempenioConfig   
this.recibidopregunta=this.preguntasConfig   
this.recibidopuntajeConfig=this.puntajeConfig
this.recibidobonosConfig=this.bonosConfig
this.recibidodinamizadoresConfig=this.dinamizadoresConfig 

}
```

**Kaypacha.Component.html (Padre)**

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="column" style="padding-top: 10px;"> 
            <app-panel 
                [recibidopregunta]="recibidopregunta" 
                [recibidodesempeno]="recibidodesempeno"   
                [recibidopuntajeConfig]="recibidopuntajeConfig" 
                [recibidobonosConfig]="recibidobonosConfig"
                [recibidodinamizadoresConfig]="recibidodinamizadoresConfig"
            >
           
            </app-panel>
```

**Panel.component.ts(Hijo)**

**Agregue los decoradores**

```
@Input() recibidodesempeno: any;
     @Input() recibidopregunta: any;
     @Input() recibidopuntajeConfig :any;
     @Input() recibidobonosConfig:any
     @Input() recibidodinamizadoresConfig:any;

public ngOnInit(): void { 
if(this.recibidopregunta ==null){
            this.preguntasConfig=cloneDeep(preguntasConfig);
            
        }
        else { 
            this.preguntasConfig=this.recibidopregunta
        }
        if(this.recibidopuntajeConfig == null){
            this.puntajeConfig=cloneDeep(puntajeConfig);
        }
        else{
            this.puntajeConfig=this.recibidopuntajeConfig
        }
        if(this.recibidobonosConfig==null){
            this.bonosConfig=cloneDeep(bonosConfig);
        }
        else{
            this.bonosConfig=this.recibidobonosConfig
        }
        if(this.recibidodinamizadoresConfig==null){
            this.dinamizadoresConfig={i1:baseDinamizadoresConfig.line,i2:baseDinamizadoresConfig.line};
        }
        else
        {
            this.dinamizadoresConfig=this.recibidodinamizadoresConfig
        } 
       
        this.desempenioConfig=this.recibidodesempeno  
}
```

Comment: si es una forma de comunicación podes mirar :http://developinginspanish.com/2018/05/19/3-formas-de-comunicarse-entre-componentes-angular/ y https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/angularya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=80&codigo=80&inicio=60

Comment: @nestdan mil gracias , me recomiendas algún libro o vídeo para aprender desde 0

Comment: @nestdan como se puede hacer para cuando haga clic el cuerpo cambie es decir cambie de componente a otro componente

Comment: para manejar rutas se usa routerLink desde la vista para cada ruta especifica no se si te referís a esto ? Si  hay un tutorial web 
 completo desde 0  de Academia Binaria la parte de rutas -->https://academia-binaria.com/paginas-y-rutas-angular-spa/

Comment: en cuanto a libros ng-book  de Nate Murray según la versión lo podes descargar free  y codigo en github Tambien como inicial  inicial el gran libro de angular de Oriols

Comment: @nestdan si, lo que pasa me ha dicho que se cambie el cuerpo porque arriba en la cabecera va ver opciones segun esa opción nomas se debe cambiar el cuerpo sin hacer direccionamiento es decir la página se llama así
http:localhost/kaypacha
cuando se cambie de cabcera no haga esto
http:localhost/kaypacha/cuerpo
sino que siga en el mismo url

Comment: @nestdan mil gracias lo revisare y profundizaré más, se poquito angular y deseo aprender

Comment: cambiar la ruta, sin cambiar la URL en el navegador.
 Esto navega a una nueva URL sin introducir un nuevo estado en el historial
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });

Comment: en el link <a href="#" [skipLocationChange]="true" ...>Link</a> no conozco otra forma mas que la anterior con el router y esta en el link no se si es lo que buscas ?